# How does Varnish storage data?

Tags: magento2.3, varnish

I'm integrating Varnish for my site Magento ver 2.3 with the web server using Nginx.

During learning varnish, I encountered some problems:

- When a request is sent to the server, where is the Varnish's cache stored?
- Where does varnish's cache come from?

Thanks, everyone for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish can store data in different backends. Default is memory with limited size.

More about varnish storage configuration: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.3/users-guide/storage-backends.html

Comment: Hi @MaciejHarbuz. 
I know, there're two ways to storage varnish's cache , memory or disk. 
however, I want to learn more clearly.

Comment: In provided link, there is some details about every storage type. Please give me a clue about what kind of detail is important to you.